# "to be” vs “to become”

Tags: word-usage

Are there any differences between the meaning of these sentences?

- When you left, I **was** sad.
- When you left, I **became** sad.

Comment: In your *exact* context, there's probably no difference (it's not really likely that the speaker means he was sad *at the actual time* the addressee left; almost certainly the feeling of sadness came *immediately after* that departure). In a slightly different context *(When you **arrived,** I was/became sad)* there would definitely be a difference - ***was*** implies I was already sad (for some unspecified reason) at the time when you arrived, ***became*** strongly implies your arrival ***caused*** my sadness.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is one of them more natural?

Comment: Yes - it's far more "natural" to use ***was*** in your exact context, even though strictly speaking (based on the semantic difference between ***to be*** and ***to become***) it's pretty obvious ***became*** is a more "accurate" choice of verb. The fact of the matter is the intended *meaning* (my sadness came to pass ***when = immediately after*** you left; I wasn't sad *before* that) is so obvious it doesn't matter if the choice of verb doesn't "unambiguously" convey that. If the "unusual" meaning (I was sad both before and at the time you left) was intended we'd use different phrasing anyway

Comment: ...the "became" version is somewhat "literary". The effect of using it is to focus more attention on the (potentially, *extended*) ***process / transition***, perhaps making the speaker sound more "needy", and deserving of sympathy. But like I say, it's a slightly affected / literary usage for your cited context. Probably best avoided by non-native speakers, who won't easily be able to tell which contexts it's likely to work in.